# nested regression model using lmer?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-models

I have to look for the affect of crater degradation, rim irregularity (RI), radii variation (RV), depth-diameter rati (Dd) and mantled rim percentage (MRP) on crater rim thermal inertia. 138 craters (ID) were analyzed which are nested within 18 scenes (Scenes). Thermal inertia values depends on the error associated with that individual scenes.

Also I have to look for the error between thermal inertia and rim irregularity based on repeat measurement, and vice versa.

To test correlation between TI and RI

```
M0 <- lmer(TI ~ RI + RV + Dd + MRP + (RI | Scene)
M1 <- lmer(TI ~ RV + Dd + MRP + (RI | Scene)
anova(M1, M0)
```

How to estimate the error between TI and RI, TI and RV, TI~Dd respectively?

I want to know if I am on the right track or not ?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *error* ?

Comment: I have to plot error bars for the relationship between thermal inertia and rim irregularity of craters covered by different scenes, The TI values within a scene are dependent on the error associated with that individual scene, so for every scene error must be computed. The scene itself has 20% error.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what you mean by "error" ? For example are you trying to estimate a *measurement error*, are you talking about *standard error* , or something else entirely. What is your actual research question ?

Comment: Sorry, I am talking about standard error.

Comment: How to plot scatter plot with error bars for individual scenes?

Comment: standard error of *what* ?

Comment: standard error for the correlation between the variables for each individual nested in scene.

Comment: A standard error is associated with a particular *estimate* from a model. You will not get a standard error for each individual. What you are asking for does not make sense.

Comment: I am trying to plot the predicted values with error bars for each scene.